# JOIN - 2 tasks - sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tasks:

**1. FIRST TASK**

Show  first_name, last_name (from employees), job_title, employee_id (from jobs) start_date, end_date (from job_history)

My idea:

```
SELECT s.employee_id
    , first_name
    , last_name
    , job_title
    , employee_id
    , start_date
    , end_date
FROM employees
INNER JOIN jobs hp
    on s.employee_id = hp.employee_id
INNER JOIN job_history
    on hp.jobs = h.jobs
```

1. I know it doesn't work. I'm receiving: "HP"."EMPLOYEE_ID": invalid identifier
2. What does it mean "on s.employee_id = hp.employee_id". Maybe I should write sthg else instead of this.

**2. SECOND TASK**

Show department_name (from departments), average and max salary for each department (those data are from employees) and how many employees are working in those departments (from employees). Choose only departments with more than 1 person. The result round to 2 decimal places.

I have the pieces, but i don't know to connect it
My idea:

```
SELECT department_name,average(salary),max(salary),count(employees_id)
FROM employees
INNER JOIN departments 
on employees_id = departments_id
HAVING count(department) > 1


SELECT ROUND(average(salary),2) from employees
```

Comment: Your first query. `s.employee_id`.  I don't see a table called `s`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your queries a bit by improving table aliasing. Hopefully, if the right columns are present in the tables as you say, it should work:

```
SELECT s.employee_id, s.first_name, s.last_name, 
hp.job_title, hp.employee_id,
h.start_date, h.end_date
FROM employees s
INNER JOIN jobs hp
on s.employee_id = hp.employee_id
INNER JOIN job_history h
on hp.jobs = h.jobs;
```

When we say `on s.employee_id = hp.employee_id` it means that if, for example, there is an `employee_id = 1234` present in both the tables `employees` and `jobs`, then SQL will bring all the columns from both the tables in the same line that corresponds to `employee_id = 1234`. You can now pick different columns in the `SELECT` clause as if they are in the same/single table(which was not the case before joining). This is the main logic behind SQL joins.

As to your 2nd task, try the below query. I made some modifications in aggregation by introducing `COUNT(DISTINCT s.employees_id)`. If the same `employees_id` is present twice for some reason, you still want to count that as one person.

```
SELECT d.department_name, avg(s.salary), max(s.salary), count(distinct s.employees_id)
FROM employees s 
INNER JOIN departments d
on e.employees_id = d.departments_id
GROUP BY d.department_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.employees_id) > 1;
```

Let me know if there is still any issue. Hopefully, this works.

Comment: thanks for your help! The first one is ok, but the second one no :( I'm receiving "SQL command not properly ended". Simple ; doesn;t work :(

Comment: I just made a couple of edits(added ";" at the end of queries and added count(distinct s.employees_id) in select clause.